# replace values in pandas based on other two column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have problem with replacement values in a column conditional other two columns.

For example we have three columns. A, B, and C
Columns A and B are both booleans, containing True and False, and column C contains three values: "Payroll", "Social", and "Other".

When in columns A and B are True in column C we have value "Payroll".
I want to change values in column C where both column A and B are True.

I tried following code: but gives me this error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'where'":

```
data1.replace({'C' : { 'Payroll', 'Social'}},inplace=True).where((data1['A'] == True) & (data1['B'] == True))
```

but gives me this error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'where'":

What can be done to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all `True`s per rows and then assign output by filtered `DataFrame` by boolean mask:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'C': ['Payroll','Other','Payroll','Social'],
    'A': [True, True, True, False],
    'B':[False, True, True, False]
})
print (data1)
       A      B        C
0   True  False  Payroll
1   True   True    Other
2   True   True  Payroll
3  False  False   Social

m = data1[['A', 'B']].all(axis=1)
#same output as
#m = data1['A'] & data1['B']
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

print (data1[m])
      A     B        C
1  True  True    Other
2  True  True  Payroll
```

---

```
data1[m] = data1[m].replace({'C' : { 'Payroll':'Social'}})
print (data1)
       A      B        C
0   True  False  Payroll
1   True   True    Other
2   True   True   Social
3  False  False   Social
```

Comment: okay, but where is conditions, which have to be satisfied in columns A and B?

Comment: It is hidden in `all`, but is possible use also `m = data1['A'] & data1['B']`

Comment: #jezrael, after this conditional replacement I need to export it in excel file and will there be original column C, where the values are already changed?

Comment: So need export only row 2 from sample to excel?

Comment: no, I want to export entire dataframe, with changes in column C inplace. is it possible?

Comment: I think not, need assign output back.

Comment: So, you're saying to assain new output to the old dataframe?

Comment: Well you can make a copy of dataframe and perform operation on that copy

Comment: Code works first filter by mask `m` and then replace only these rows. Then replaced output is rewrite back to column `C`, but only for filtered rows. So first value in sample is not replaced, but 3. yes.

Comment: okay guys. I'll try both methods as suggested and will see if I get desired output

Comment: @jezrael make a deep copy and perform the operations you suggested!

Comment: I can add timings.

Comment: aah, okay #jezrael

Comment: #jezrael can we continue chat here or somewhere else? this problem is critically important and I need help. I will try your method and if not work can we come up another solution?

Comment: gmail chat is OK?

Comment: But first idea - there are not trailing whitespaces in `C` column? Check it by `print (df['C'].tolist())`

Comment: totally ok. n.okroshiashvili@gmail.com that's my mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158866/discussion-between-nodar-okroshiashvili-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `apply` function to do this

```
def change_value(dataframe):
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
      if row['A'] == row['B'] == True:
           row['C'] = # Change to whatever value you want
      else:
           row ['C'] = # Change how ever you want
```